# Find $f$ such that solutions of $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + f(n)$ are in $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: functions

Find $f(n)$ that $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + f(n)$  will be $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ or show that it can't be proved.

Well, I already solved this for $f(n) = \sqrt{n} \rightarrow \Theta(\sqrt{n}logn)$ and also for $f(n) = n \rightarrow \Theta(n)$ with Master Theorem $2$ and $3$.

But I cant seem to find $f(n)$ that will yield $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$. I believe it can't be proved, and I have no idea how to say that it can be proved.

Comment: One asks that $T(4^n)/2^n=T(1)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(4^k)/2^k$ is in $\Theta(1)$, hence every $f$ such that the series $\sum\limits_nf(4^n)/2^n$ converges is a solution, say, assuming $T(1)$ is nonnegative, $f(n)$ nonnegative and in $O(n^a)$ for some $a<\frac12$.

Comment: @Did My math knowledge isn't so high. Can you explain more simply please? I didn't understand How you got $T(4^n)/2^n = ...$ and is it possible to prove? and thanks Did!

Comment: @Did The first line. I didn't understand anything.. LHS AND RHS

Comment: Is this typically *non-specific* or what?

Comment: @Did How did you conclude that from the given equation in the question. how does it help to prove?

Comment: You see $T(4^n)/2^n$ in my comment. Did you try to find a relation between $S(n)=T(4^n)/2^n$ and $S(n-1)$ and to see what happens from there? (No, I will not provide a full solution, ready to be handed-in. Sorry for that (or not sorry).)

Comment: @Did Consider $n^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and Master theorem 1.

Comment: You say, $n^{1/5}$? Good, you managed to find "$f(n)$ nonnegative and in some $O(n^a)$", as recommended in my comment (but frankly, you can forget "Master theorem 1", whatever the name means). Congrats.

Comment: @Did Yup. Thanks Did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
$f(n) = n^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and Master theorem 1